# PHP ImageCreateFromJpeg failing with error after migrating to PHP8.0

Tags: php

Migrating from PHP 7.3 to PHP 8.0 my ImageCreateFromJpeg() and other calls requiring the php_gd2.dll fail to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php_gd2.dll has changed name to php_gd.dll BUT it is still refered to as php_gd2.dll in the default PHP.INI file (as supplied with PHP8.0)

So despite including the correct php_gd.dll in the EXT folder they forgot to change the name of the reference in the packaged default PHP.INI file.